# Alternative firmware for Belkin N1 vision

Tags: router, dd-wrt

Me and routers ... it's never been a happy marriage and probably never will.
I've had 3 routers, a d-link DIR615, Belkin N1 Vision and a linksys WRT54g.

I've been most happy with the linksys since that is the only one that works out of the box and doesn't drop connection or has other annoying flaws.

Recently i dug op my d-link again only to be confronted with the buggy firmware again so i decided it was time for action and i slammed DDWRT on it. Works flawlessly now.

Now i was looking to do the same thing with my Belkin N1 Vision (which has even worse firmware) but it seems DDWRT isn't available for it yet.

Now here's my question, does anyone know of other opensource firmware for the N1 Vision? I've checked tomato but it doesn't list among the supported routers.

Comment: I'd like to know too! It doesn't seem like dd-wrt is being developed anymore.